# refactor momentjs formatting to data-fns

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, refactoring, date-fns

I am wondering what the best way to refactor this formatting of a dateinput from momentjs to date-fns would be.

For context: There is an inputfield with the type date. A user can enter a date but there are some inputs that we would like to format, for instance, 01/01/2022 or 01012022 should be formatted for the user to 01-01-2022.

```
     function formatDateInput(value: string) {
         let date = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
         date = moment(date, ['D M YYYY', 'DMYYYY'], true);
         if (date.isValid()) {
           return date.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
         }
         return value;
      }
```

I have tried to following:

```
     function formatDateInput(value: string) {
         let date = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '');
         date = parse(date, 'dMyyyy', new Date());
         if (isValid(date)) {
           return format(date, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
         }
         return value;
      }
```

This still leaves me with the edge cases `01012`, I think that is done by moment by adding the strict param? Any ideas and suggestions to rewrite the function (differently) are very welcome.

Comment: The strategy of parsing a string to create another string that is then parsed by another parser doesn't make sense to me. If you have digits for day, month and year separated by non–digit characters, then why not just parse it once, e.g. `let [d, m, y] = dateString.match(/\d+/g); let date = new Date(y, m-1, d)`. The "edge case" 01012 seems out of range, how is it supposed to be interpreted?

Comment: So in essence I just want to format the string inside an input field with date type to return dd-mm-yyyy when it can (e.g. if someone fills out 01_01_2022 or 01/01/2022 or 01012022 e.t c.)

Comment: If you're using a date input, then you don't have to do anything. The browser will (most likely) present the date in a format based on the host system settings and handle all user interaction. All you have to do is get the value, which will be in yyyy-mm-dd format. If the browser doesn't support date inputs, then you're back to the bad old days of telling the user the expected format (via a onscreen text, not the placeholder) and enforcing it through validation.

Comment: Excuse me, didn't say that right. It is a regular input field, but certain keys are prohibited by performing a test with a pattern `/[0-9\\/:,_.\-–—\\ ]/`. This still leave the user with some way to freedom to fill out cases like 010122, which the current momentjs deals. However when giving the new code values like `010122` or `0101222` date-fns creates a date object out of it, which is undesired. I have tried to use the `isMatch(date, 'dMyyyy')` but that returns a value '010122' as true.